# Expanding brackets of the form $(a+b)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

If we have the equation

$
(a+b)^n = (a+b)\times(a+b)\times(a+b)\times \ldots \times (a+b)
$

expanding the right hand side of the above, is the sum of terms in the form $a^n$, $a^{n-1}b$,$a^{n-2}b^2$, $\ldots$, $b^n$. That is $a^{n-1}b^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$

Now, my textbook states the following

> Each term of the form $a^{n-k}b^k$ arises by choosing the variable $b$
>   from $k$ of the pairs of brackets on the right hand side of the
>   equation and the variable $a$ from the remaining $n-k$ pairs of
>   brackets.

My question is now, why? There is no proof given for this, and I am struggling to understand why the above holds.For a very simple expansion, where $k=1$ and $n=2$, we have 2 terms of the form $ab$, here its pretty easy to see from

$
(a+b)(a+b) = a(a+b) + b(a+b) = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab
$

why the statement in the book holds for this case. But, for bigger ones, such as $(a+b)^3$ i can't see it. I can see that there is 3 ways of choosing one $b$ and two $a$, for the term $a^2b$ when looking at $(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)$, but I cant relate it to the expansion of them, if that makes sense?

Comment: The general expansion formula for $(a+b)^n$ is, $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}a^{n-k} b^{k}$$ which can be proved by induction. For me induction is the easiest and the most elegant way to see that this result is correct. You might find some more details about this proof at the following link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Comment: @LinearAlgebra I do think that is an easier proof to check for the correctness of the formula, but it kind of makes the formula feel like magic because it provides no intuition on how one might derive that formula. The way the OP is learning it is a bit more instructive on that part.

Comment: @Danikar: Exactly, you are correct. Just providing some insight to the OP so that (s)he could try out the different methods. For some reason when I learnt this years ago, the teacher used a different approach. He expanded $(a+b)^2,\,(a+b)^3,(a+b)^4$ and explained about how to get the coefficients using the Pascals triangle and when we are really comfortable with writing the expansions gave the general formula and proved it with induction. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify talking about the statement a bit, let $C_i = (a + b)$ for $1\le i \le b$, so
$$(a + b)^n = C_1 \times \dots \times C_n.$$
For the case where $n = 3$ and the term $a^2b$:

If we choose $b$ from $C_1$, then we choose $a$ from $C_2$ and $C_3$.
If we choose $b$ from $C_2$, then we choose $a$ from $C_1$ and $C_3$.
If we choose $b$ from $C_3$, then we choose $a$ from $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Thus the coefficient of $a^2b$ is $3 = \binom{3}{1}$.

More generally you should be able to see that a term of $a^{n - k}b^k$ must have taken either $a$ or a $b$ from any term $C_i$. Thus simply follows from
$$(a + b)^n = C_1 \times\dots\times C_n = (a + b)[C_1 \times\dots C_{i - 1} \times C_{i + 1} \times C_n]$$
Since each $C_i$ contributes exactly one $a$ or $b$, we end up with exactly $k$ of the choices being $b$ and exactly $n - k$ of the choices being $a$. Since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose to either take $b$ or not to take $b$ from each $C_i$, we end up with $\binom{n}{k}$ terms of $a^{n-k}b^k$.